# DHT11 + Arduino UNO + Raspberry pi3 + Windows Remote Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, iot, raspberry-pi3, firmata

I need to read with C# UWP App, a DHT11/DHT22 sensor to get temperature and the arduino is conected to an Arduino UNO.
Can I use "digitalRead" at sensor PIN and converte the values using C# library 
'sensors.dht'? Or I need to change the FirmataStandard sketch to include dht library and receive the values "cleaned"?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you check [this sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/gpioonewire)?

Comment: Yes, thanks! But this sample dont use a arduino board...

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your plan is possible utilizing [Windows Remote Arduino](https://github.com/ms-iot/remote-wiring).

But currently, there is no official solution for your user case.

So you may need do some work by yourself. You need modify [GPIO OneWire DHT11 library](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/GpioOneWire) to fit your solution, such as, replace `Windows::Devices::Gpio::GpioPin::Read()` with `Microsoft::Maker::RemoteWiring::RemoteDevice::digitalRead()` and so on. Also note the time sequence due to [DHT11/22 datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf).

Finally, you may need sufficient test to ensure this solution works as expected.

Comment: Hello Rita!
Thanks for your help.
I decided to use firmata protocol to comunicate and get values, like a integer, from arduino board already processed.